testing user function of Angular firebase
right now I have a code like that
import { Auth, signOut, user } from '@angular/fire/auth';

@Component({})
export class FooComponent {
  protected readonly user = user(this.fireAuth);
  constructor(
    private readonly fireAuth: Auth,
  ) {}

  protected async logout(): Promise<void> {
    await signOut(this.fireAuth);
  }
}

and I want to test it, for the Auth I can mock it easily, but my problem with the user and signOut functions
if I mocked only the Auth like that
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { Auth } from '@angular/fire/auth';

describe('FooComponent', () => {
  let component: FooComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<FooComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const mockAuth = {};

    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        FooComponent,
      ],
      providers: [{ provide: Auth, useValue: mockAuth }],
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FooComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});

I get this error

Error: Either AngularFireModule has not been provided in your AppModule (this can be done manually or implictly using
provideFirebaseApp) or you're calling an AngularFire method outside of an NgModule (which is not supported).

importing AngularFireModule doesn't help

I'm not sure what you mean by "my problem with the user and signOut functions".  Is there any error message?

if I mock only the Auth yes, updated the question to add more details
